# LibGDX Scene2D: Actions won't work at all for actors inside groups

Tags: libgdx, action, actor, scene2d

I am trying to fade an Actor out using the Action FadeOut. However, I've discovered that the no actions work at all for my objects. The hierarchy of my classes are like this:

```java
Actor -> MoveableObject -> Knight

Stage -> KnightGroup (Group) -> Knight
```

Actions for my Knight actors do not work at all. However, actions for my KnightGroup group works. Here is the code for my Knight:

```java
public class Knight extends Players {
public Knight() {
    setWidth(96);
    setHeight(96);
    setPosition(100, 90);

    //Doesn't work
    AlphaAction action = new AlphaAction();
    action.setAlpha(0f);
    action.setDuration(1f);
    addAction(action);

    //Doesn't work
    addAction(fadeOut(1f));
    addAction(Actions.scaleBy(1f, 1f));
}

@Override
public void act(float delta){
    super.act(delta);
}


@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.setColor(getColor().r, getColor().g, getColor().b, getColor().a);
    batch.draw(animation[currentState], getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
}
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is. Actions in `MoveableObject` (the parent of Knight) doesn't work either. My best guess is that wrapping actors in a `Group` will `render` the `actions` of those actors invalid. The `KnightGroup` is a pretty crucial part of my code though and I would have to do a lot of refactoring to take it out. Can someone else shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Do you call stage.act(delta)? Does a moveBy/moveTo Action work?

Comment: Yes, stage.act(delta) is called. Everything works except for actions. moveTo actions don't work either.

Comment: In your Players class in act(delta) do you call super.act(delta)? Does that act(delta) go back to Actor.act(float delta), because the Action.act(delta) is called inside Actor.act(delta)

Comment: That was it! I was missing a super.act() at the top most level of my class hierarchy. After I added it, things worked as expected. Thank you SO much, man!

Comment: I added it as an answer so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 6):

In the `Actor` class the method `act(float delta)` calls `act(delta)` for all registered `Action`s of this `Actor`. So you have to make sure, that you call `super.act(delta)` in every subclass of `Actor`, so that the `act(delta)` method in `Actor` gets called.